# SQL Server Stored Procedure Select Into statement not completing

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm having an issue with a stored procedure which SQL Server being executed as a scheduled task through Task Manager. I have a batch file containing the EXECUTE statement which is called by Task Scheduler. Platforms is SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

The batch file code

```
@echo off 
SQLCmd -S  lccc-cpc-sql -E -d NTSR -Q "Execute update_vw_NTSR_Base_AllRecords_Labels_new_proc"
```

This SP does the following:

1. Drops a table
2. Recreates it with updated data using a SELECT INTO statement

Problem: It's running the `DROP` statement, but failing on the `SELECT INTO`. Here's what's weird though:

If I execute the sp through SSMS (right click the sp, choose Execute) OR, view a query editor, run the code to drop the table and the SELECT INTO statement, it finishes correctly. It's a very large `SELECT INTO` statement - hundreds of columns and about 100 joins. The purpose is to join a lot of lookup tables to values so I have one place for my users to go for labeled data and some variables computed for user friendliness. It's messy, but it's what I have to work with.

Query timeout is set to 0 (no limit). This only happened recently as I added more columns and variables but it seems it'd fail called through any method, not just through the batch file. Any thoughts on how to make this work as-is (ie without breaking this up into multiple SELECT INTO statements)?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say it's `not completing`, do you mean it's running for a long time so you are cancelling it?

Comment: What actually happens? "*It Fails*" tells us nothing.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22020/running-queries-with-sqlcmd-vs-running-queries-with-ssms

Comment: @DavidG, it runs a long time (typically 3 mins or so) then stops. I am not cancelling it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I mean that the batch completes and the table is dropped, but it is not created again with the select into statement. The INTO statement fails to create a table. I do not receive an error